# What is the correct way to use $stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Decently new to Angular, trying to figure out the correct way to use $stateProvider.

here is my current setup

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('users_orders', {
        url: '/users/:userId/orders',
        templateUrl: '/assets/orders/users/index.html',
        controller: 'UserOrdersController'
      })
      .state('users_orders_edit', {
        url: '/users/:userId/orders/:orderId/edit',
        templateUrl: '/assets/orders/users/edit.html',
        controller: 'UserOrderController'
      })
    }])
```

This setup works fine, but what i would like to do is something like this.

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('users_orders', {
        url: '/users/:userId/orders',
        templateUrl: '/assets/orders/users/index.html',
        controller: 'UserOrdersController'
      })
      .state('users_orders.edit', {
        url: '/:orderId/edit',
        views: {
         edit: {
           templateUrl: '/assets/orders/users/edit.html',
           controller: 'UserOrderController'
         }
        }
      })
    }])
```

This setup doesnt work though, when i click on my edit link it changes the url, but stays on the same page.  Am I doing the setup wrong?

Comment: What's the HTML structure of `index.html` ? More specifically, the `ui-view` section

Comment: have a look here should be everything explained https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views with examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the second solution work you should have in `index.html` a 
    `<div ui-view="edit"></div>`

Comment: I tried this one so its working but is it possible to store that edit entry from $stateProvider

Comment: If you want to use named views  in `$stateprovider` you must add them in the template also, like in the answer. So, to answer your question, it's not possible to define those views only in $stateProvider

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#example---name-matching